# Event​Target​.add​Event​Listener() not working after innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, innerhtml, event-listener

I dynamically create a checkbox that has an [EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Unfortunately the EventListener doesn't work if I change the text of the checkbox-label with `innerHTML`:

```js
let label = document.createElement('label'),
    input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
input.addEventListener('change', () => alert('Change Detected'));

label.appendChild(input);
document.body.appendChild(label);
label.innerHTML += 'Select Me!';
```

**How can I circumvent this problem and why does it even exist?**

Here a working snippet without the `innerHTML`:

```js
let label = document.createElement('label'),
    input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
input.addEventListener('change', () => alert('Change Detected'));

label.appendChild(input);
document.body.appendChild(label);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you concatenate to the `innerHTML` of an element, its contents are *cleared*, the existing HTML string is concatenated with the new string, and then the container's contents are re-calculated according to the new HTML string. ~~Listeners~~ Elements attached to elements previously in the container do not survive the serialization process - the children of the container after changing `innerHTML` are *new*.

Append a text node instead:

```js
let label = document.createElement('label');
let input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
input.addEventListener('change', () => alert('Change Detected'));

label.appendChild(input);
document.body.appendChild(label);
label.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Select Me!'));
```

Or use `insertAdjacentHTML`:

```js
let label = document.createElement('label');
let input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
input.addEventListener('change', () => alert('Change Detected'));

label.appendChild(input);
document.body.appendChild(label);
label.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'Select Me!');
```

Comment: It's completely up to you. I don't really have an opinion, they both work just fine. If you're inserting non-trivial markup, it's probably nicer to use `insertAdjacentHTML` because that way the new HTML structure is clearer (when you can see the markup directly, rather than having to parse through the `createElement`s and `appendChild`s to see what's connected to what)

Comment: "Listeners attached to elements previously in the container do not survive the serialization process." that's not what happens no. `input` has been removed from the DOM, hence, the one `<input>` you have here is not the previous `input` one. And this one doesn't have any event attached to it. But the Event Listener is still very alive (for as long as the GC collects `input`). https://jsfiddle.net/bqvgmxLd/